# Pandas dataframe only storing last value of iteration

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe "df" I am trying to store all the values of the for the variable "euclidean length" with the corressponding "fullpath" value. I manage to print the pairs as a program output but not to be stored into a dataframe. The dataframe is only storing the last value pair.

```
import math
import itertools
import sys
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import pandas as pd 


def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 +(y1-y2)**2)

def total_distance(fullpath):
    if len(fullpath) <= 1:
        return 0

    total = 0
    for i in range(1, len(fullpath)):
        pointA = fullpath[i-1]
        pointB = fullpath[i]
        total += distance(pointA[0], pointA[1], pointB[0], pointB[1])
        return total

n = 10
start_points= (0,1) 
end_points=(10,10)
generate_dots = 8
constraint_circle_radius = 1
pass_through_dots = 3
space = []

for x in range(constraint_circle_radius, n - constraint_circle_radius + 1):
    for y in range(constraint_circle_radius, n - constraint_circle_radius + 1):
        space.append((x,y))

for path in all_possible_path:
    fullpath = [start_points]+ list(path) + [end_points]
    euclidean_length = total_distance(fullpath)
    print("Path: {} has total length:{}".format(fullpath, euclidean_length))
    data = {'Path': [fullpath],
           'E Length': [euclidean_length]}
    #convert to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

Comment: Of course it does so, because on each loop you are creating the dataframe df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here are the offending lines:

```
for path in all_possible_path:
    fullpath = [start_points]+ list(path) + [end_points]
    euclidean_length = total_distance(fullpath)
    print("Path: {} has total length:{}".format(fullpath, euclidean_length))
    data = {'Path': [fullpath],
           'E Length': [euclidean_length]}
    #convert to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You create a new data frame for each iteration.

Do this instead:

```
paths = []    
for path in all_possible_path:
    fullpath = [start_points]+ list(path) + [end_points]
    euclidean_length = total_distance(fullpath)
    print("Path: {} has total length:{}".format(fullpath, euclidean_length))

    paths.append({'Path': [fullpath],
                           'E Length': [euclidean_length]})
df = pd.DataFrame(paths)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to the following:
```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for path in all_possible_path:
    fullpath = [start_points]+ list(path) + [end_points]
    euclidean_length = total_distance(fullpath)
data = {'Path': [fullpath],
           'E Length': [euclidean_length]}
    #convert to dataframe
df
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. How could I create the iteration for adding the values for each loop iteration without creating a new dataframe?

Comment: create a list instead, append to the list and then create a data frame where the data is that list.